# Сделать ссылку для скачивания JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Есть JSP страница необходимо сделать ссылку для скачивания файла. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала вам необходимо создать Servlet для загрузки файла. Например:

```
@WebServlet("/download")
public class DownloadServlet extends HttpServlet { ... }
```

Теперь опишите метод `doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)`:

```
     // тип данных, которые вы отправляете
     // например application/pdf, text/plain, text/html, image/jpg
     response.setContentType("ТИП_ДАННЫХ_MIME");
     response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=ВАШЕ_КАСТОМНОЕ_ИМЯ_ФАЙЛА.ext");

     // файл, который вы отправляете
     File my_file = new File("ИМЯ_ФАЙЛА");

     // отправить файл в response
     OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
     FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(my_file);

     byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
     int length;

     while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
        out.write(buffer, 0, length);
     }

     // освободить ресурсы
     in.close();
     out.flush();
```

Это очень простой пример загрузки файла.

Теперь в example.jsp необходимо просто разместить ссылку, например

`<a href="/download">скачать файл</a>`